# How to refresh a widget with stream builder in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, stream-builder

I am trying to show data from the text file as per the data stored in shared preference i have another screen to save data in the text file i have a stream builder earlier it was future builder So i am trying to refresh the screen when coming back from second screen i tried to call a method when pop the method is getting called in the viewmodel calss of provider but the streambuilder is not getting updated
this is the code

to fetch data

```
Future<List<String>> fetchdata() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String? category = prefs.getString('category');
if (category != null) {
  lines = await locator<JsonAPI>().fetchquotes(category);
} else {
  lines = await locator<JsonAPI>().fetchquotes('quotes');
}
// data = lines as Future<List<String>>;
notifyListeners();
return lines;
}
```

stream builder

```
         var quotesdata = Provider.of<HomeViewModel>(context, listen: false);

 StreamBuilder(
              stream: quotesdata.fetchdata().asStream(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  List<String> lines = quotesdata.lines;
                  // List<String>? lines = snapshot.data as List<String>?;
                  return ScreenShotWidget(
                    homeViewModel: quotesdata,
                    list: lines,
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container();
                }
              }),
```

method that i call when pop

```
function(data) {
category = data.toString();
fetchdata();
notifyListeners();
setState() {}
}
```

any idea how to update the screen

Comment: Could you specify what quotesdata is and where it is created?

Comment: quotesdata is the object of view model class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your widget rebuilds, you get a new stream. This is a mistake. You should obtain the stream only once (for example, in initState)

```
@override
void initState() {
  _stream = quotesdata.fetchdata().asStream();
}
```

and use that stream variable with `StreamBuilder`

```
 StreamBuilder(
   stream: _stream,
```

Later, when you want to update the stream, you can do

```
setState(() {
  _stream = quotesdata.fetchdata().asStream();
})
```

to change the stream and force a refresh.

Please go over your code and change all such usages

```
 StreamBuilder(
   stream: quotesdata.fetchdata().asStream(),
```

to this kind of usage.

```
 StreamBuilder(
   stream: _stream,
```

Otherwise you may get a high backend bill someday. Right now every screen refresh does a new query to the backend.

Comment: but quotesdata is a provider object how i can use it prior initializing??

Comment: there are some ways here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60343605/how-to-use-data-from-provider-during-initstate-in-flutter-application an alternative is for parent to get it and pass it to constructor of this widget.

Comment: You just CANNOT call fetchdata() within your build function.

Comment: hey just a question when i pop the second screen does this method suppose to auto refresh ? a i have to setstate method in the function

Comment: you mean after you show this screen with the stream, you show a second screen and when you come back to this you want this to refresh?

Comment: Yes you have to do setstate. You can do this:

Comment: ```await Navigator.push(...);
setState(...)```